# Dynamic Grid Height Depending on Number of Elements

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to achieve a CSS Grid layout with two columns: the left column consists of a single element (e.g. a post) while the right column can have **up to** three posts (can have one or two, as well).

A basic example of the HTML layout would look like this:

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="primary">Potentially long text, but at most 1000px high...</div>
  <div class="secondary">Text 1...</div>
  <div class="secondary">Text 2...</div>
  <div class="secondary">Text 3...</div>
</div>
```

Since the number of posts on the right side is dynamic, I can't really define an explicit grid with three rows, or else I will have empty grid cells if I end up with fewer than three posts.

I can't use `grid-row: 1 / -1` on the left column without defining an explicit grid with three rows (at least from what I can tell).

The end goal is to have a blog post layout which features an article on the left side in full length, but only up to a specific height (e.g. 1000px, overflow hidden, text fading out), and up to three more posts on the right side with only excerpt-length of text. The columns of the grid should have equal height at all times but the right column's height should never extend the max-height set for the left column (the 1000px).
If the right side only has one or two posts, the left column should shrink accordingly. In other words, the posts on the right side should never have more whitespace than necessary because of the left column being too high.

To clarify: The height should ultimately be controlled by the right side and the posts on the right side should not be stretched if there is a very long text on the left side, instead the left side should be cut off at 1000px.

I created a codepen to illustrate my problem, or rather the situation I'm stuck in at the moment: https://codepen.io/cwardle/pen/ExZJJXL.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  column-gap: 1rem;
  padding: 2rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);
}

.primary {
  grid-row: 1 / -1;
  position: relative;
  max-height: 300px;
  background: #cecece;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.primary:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(transparent 200px, #fff);
}

.secondary {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  background: #aaa;
  margin-block-end: 1rem;
}

.secondary:last-child {
  margin-block-end: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="primary">
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A illo nisi, sint odio repellat id enim totam. Aliquid nobis ducimus veniam totam eos et reiciendis porro illum sequi distinctio? Aliquam.
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus nulla amet perferendis iure veniam? Obcaecati molestiae laborum similique voluptatibus vel libero? Molestias deserunt nemo et consequuntur quam, saepe quo ratione?
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum ut aperiam molestiae cumque nam reprehenderit repellat, quas omnis, delectus possimus id. Enim delectus quasi et cumque quas, temporibus odio alias?
    Sequi ullam nostrum nesciunt. Sed distinctio illo eos odit repellendus eum incidunt ex libero mollitia rerum, veritatis cumque pariatur sapiente aliquid autem maiores quia itaque voluptates quidem dolore ratione doloremque!
    Ea, illum quibusdam dolores enim ex laborum voluptate repellendus nostrum dicta magnam est temporibus ipsa quisquam aut placeat cupiditate animi earum optio maiores. Eos voluptatibus ad, provident optio eligendi numquam.
    Aliquam, consectetur iste eveniet ipsam iusto pariatur exercitationem, incidunt perspiciatis nostrum repudiandae, dignissimos sint quo odit! Hic unde tempore veniam temporibus dolorem totam! Velit at in, distinctio accusamus quasi minima.
    Officiis fuga natus assumenda ipsa quaerat, voluptatem rerum voluptas, dicta minus odit, sit earum nobis! Recusandae labore minus rerum modi minima est totam deleniti, eligendi sint quasi adipisci at iure?
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias suscipit dignissimos porro nihil commodi et libero, mollitia ipsa. Officia quidem delectus nemo magni doloribus facilis iste rerum cum eum soluta!
    Omnis laboriosam illo nisi! Unde tempora exercitationem culpa, architecto dignissimos eum ratione amet doloremque, quam expedita laboriosam voluptas laborum ipsam aliquid sit saepe hic suscipit quidem illum molestiae nisi soluta.
    Eveniet natus autem vitae, quasi praesentium pariatur nulla dolorem repellat? Quidem eos eum consectetur eaque mollitia laboriosam vitae libero fugit perspiciatis debitis officiis beatae, commodi odio id reprehenderit tenetur tempora.
    Deserunt assumenda debitis, ullam mollitia molestias neque iste obcaecati commodi, vitae quasi laborum aperiam libero itaque eveniet eaque nihil explicabo impedit maxime, ducimus dolores. Rerum voluptate praesentium doloremque dolor autem!
    Vitae eius adipisci quisquam, aliquid nemo nostrum inventore rerum molestiae iure vel officia, delectus reiciendis autem dolore, enim earum. Doloremque autem vero amet enim, possimus animi temporibus consequatur aperiam cum.
    Fugit aperiam minus expedita voluptates dolor! Quia nihil ducimus dolores error aliquid totam eos alias non, cupiditate tenetur officia necessitatibus odio distinctio sequi quas nostrum, esse dolore vero consectetur earum.
    Sunt ratione id totam, itaque doloremque, consectetur pariatur, quisquam deleniti expedita asperiores molestias perspiciatis eius. Rem ratione sapiente rerum eum accusamus maxime quos. Corporis, autem ipsum. At velit sunt tempora!
    Animi blanditiis officia, reiciendis hic totam amet ea repellendus voluptatem quae eos! Sunt debitis pariatur perferendis harum consequatur natus cumque sapiente minus ut quae, quo reprehenderit ratione exercitationem omnis tenetur!
    Nesciunt enim mollitia non rerum similique rem nisi ab corrupti, ea commodi quas! Commodi repudiandae alias reprehenderit deleniti magni repellendus voluptatibus quod aperiam, veniam laborum distinctio molestiae consequuntur corporis soluta.
    Possimus dolore dolores neque distinctio obcaecati praesentium, perspiciatis saepe autem mollitia repellendus quos nulla aliquam alias temporibus, illum deleniti nesciunt, veritatis et odio. Tempore aspernatur odit, explicabo nulla totam cupiditate.
  </div>
  <div class="secondary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi doloremque tempore dicta nisi vel omnis, rem repudiandae explicabo provident voluptatibus ut magnam atque natus cumque necessitatibus quisquam. Nesciunt, minus maiores.</div>
  <div class="secondary">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur voluptas vel blanditiis corrupti earum, ipsa quasi corporis dignissimos doloribus sunt, laudantium exercitationem natus, sit accusamus facere quisquam suscipit reiciendis mollitia.</div>
  <div class="secondary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab porro, animi a, molestiae expedita veritatis recusandae repudiandae eligendi id deserunt tempore tenetur unde iste, earum sed nulla quis. Fuga, minus!</div>
</div>
```

I would highly appreciate any help or pointers you could offer. Thanks.

Comment: *In other words, the posts on the right side should never have more whitespace than necessary because of the left column being too high.*  Makes no sense.  Either the left or the right needs to *control* the height.  If the left has max-height: 1000px and then the right has 3 that have white space.. does the left shrink?  What if there is only one on the right?

Comment: I actually stated what happened if the right side has only one (or two) posts in the sentence prior to the one you quoted: "If the right side only has one or two posts, the left column should shrink accordingly. "
The height should ultimately be controlled by the right side. What I meant with the sentence you quoted is, that the posts on the right side should not be stretched if there is a very long text on the left side, instead the left side should be cut off at 1000px.

Comment: So the 1000px max height is actually a restriction on the right.  Otherwise you can have your right posts exceed 1000px the left won't and that would look weird.

Comment: @ErikPhilips yeah, that's a better way of describing it. It made me think about it a bit differently and maybe that helps with a solution. I'll post about it if I find anything. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`position:absolute` can do the job here:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
  padding: 2rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows:1fr; /* all row equal in height */
  position:relative;
}

.primary {
  top:2rem;
  left:2rem;
  bottom:2rem;
  width:calc(50% - 2.5rem); /* take half the width (the first 1fr) */
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 300px;
  background: #cecece;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.primary:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(transparent 200px, #fff);
}

.secondary {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  background: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="primary">
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A illo nisi, sint odio repellat id enim totam. Aliquid nobis ducimus veniam totam eos et reiciendis porro illum sequi distinctio? Aliquam.
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus nulla amet perferendis iure veniam? Obcaecati molestiae laborum similique voluptatibus vel libero? Molestias deserunt nemo et consequuntur quam, saepe quo ratione?
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum ut aperiam molestiae cumque nam reprehenderit repellat, quas omnis, delectus possimus id. Enim delectus quasi et cumque quas, temporibus odio alias?
    Sequi ullam nostrum nesciunt. Sed distinctio illo eos odit repellendus eum incidunt ex libero mollitia rerum, veritatis cumque pariatur sapiente aliquid autem maiores quia itaque voluptates quidem dolore ratione doloremque!
    Ea, illum quibusdam dolores enim ex laborum voluptate repellendus nostrum dicta magnam est temporibus ipsa quisquam aut placeat cupiditate animi earum optio maiores. Eos voluptatibus ad, provident optio eligendi numquam.
    Aliquam, consectetur iste eveniet ipsam iusto pariatur exercitationem, incidunt perspiciatis nostrum repudiandae, dignissimos sint quo odit! Hic unde tempore veniam temporibus dolorem totam! Velit at in, distinctio accusamus quasi minima.
    Officiis fuga natus assumenda ipsa quaerat, voluptatem rerum voluptas, dicta minus odit, sit earum nobis! Recusandae labore minus rerum modi minima est totam deleniti, eligendi sint quasi adipisci at iure?
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias suscipit dignissimos porro nihil commodi et libero, mollitia ipsa. Officia quidem delectus nemo magni doloribus facilis iste rerum cum eum soluta!
    Omnis laboriosam illo nisi! Unde tempora exercitationem culpa, architecto dignissimos eum ratione amet doloremque, quam expedita laboriosam voluptas laborum ipsam aliquid sit saepe hic suscipit quidem illum molestiae nisi soluta.
    Eveniet natus autem vitae, quasi praesentium pariatur nulla dolorem repellat? Quidem eos eum consectetur eaque mollitia laboriosam vitae libero fugit perspiciatis debitis officiis beatae, commodi odio id reprehenderit tenetur tempora.
    Deserunt assumenda debitis, ullam mollitia molestias neque iste obcaecati commodi, vitae quasi laborum aperiam libero itaque eveniet eaque nihil explicabo impedit maxime, ducimus dolores. Rerum voluptate praesentium doloremque dolor autem!
    Vitae eius adipisci quisquam, aliquid nemo nostrum inventore rerum molestiae iure vel officia, delectus reiciendis autem dolore, enim earum. Doloremque autem vero amet enim, possimus animi temporibus consequatur aperiam cum.
    Fugit aperiam minus expedita voluptates dolor! Quia nihil ducimus dolores error aliquid totam eos alias non, cupiditate tenetur officia necessitatibus odio distinctio sequi quas nostrum, esse dolore vero consectetur earum.
    Sunt ratione id totam, itaque doloremque, consectetur pariatur, quisquam deleniti expedita asperiores molestias perspiciatis eius. Rem ratione sapiente rerum eum accusamus maxime quos. Corporis, autem ipsum. At velit sunt tempora!
    Animi blanditiis officia, reiciendis hic totam amet ea repellendus voluptatem quae eos! Sunt debitis pariatur perferendis harum consequatur natus cumque sapiente minus ut quae, quo reprehenderit ratione exercitationem omnis tenetur!
    Nesciunt enim mollitia non rerum similique rem nisi ab corrupti, ea commodi quas! Commodi repudiandae alias reprehenderit deleniti magni repellendus voluptatibus quod aperiam, veniam laborum distinctio molestiae consequuntur corporis soluta.
    Possimus dolore dolores neque distinctio obcaecati praesentium, perspiciatis saepe autem mollitia repellendus quos nulla aliquam alias temporibus, illum deleniti nesciunt, veritatis et odio. Tempore aspernatur odit, explicabo nulla totam cupiditate.
  </div>
  <div class="secondary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi doloremque tempore dicta nisi vel omnis, rem repudiandae explicabo provident voluptatibus ut magnam atque natus cumque necessitatibus quisquam. Nesciunt, minus maiores.</div>
  <div class="secondary">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur voluptas vel blanditiis corrupti earum, ipsa quasi corporis dignissimos doloribus sunt, laudantium exercitationem natus, sit accusamus facere quisquam suscipit reiciendis mollitia.</div>
  <div class="secondary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab porro, animi a, molestiae expedita veritatis recusandae repudiandae eligendi id deserunt tempore tenetur unde iste, earum sed nulla quis. Fuga, minus!</div>
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="primary">
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A illo nisi, sint odio repellat id enim totam. Aliquid nobis ducimus veniam totam eos et reiciendis porro illum sequi distinctio? Aliquam.
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus nulla amet perferendis iure veniam? Obcaecati molestiae laborum similique voluptatibus vel libero? Molestias deserunt nemo et consequuntur quam, saepe quo ratione?
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum ut aperiam molestiae cumque nam reprehenderit repellat, quas omnis, delectus possimus id. Enim delectus quasi et cumque quas, temporibus odio alias?
    Sequi ullam nostrum nesciunt. Sed distinctio illo eos odit repellendus eum incidunt ex libero mollitia rerum, veritatis cumque pariatur sapiente aliquid autem maiores quia itaque voluptates quidem dolore ratione doloremque!
    Ea, illum quibusdam dolores enim ex laborum voluptate repellendus nostrum dicta magnam est temporibus ipsa quisquam aut placeat cupiditate animi earum optio maiores. Eos voluptatibus ad, provident optio eligendi numquam.
    Aliquam, consectetur iste eveniet ipsam iusto pariatur exercitationem, incidunt perspiciatis nostrum repudiandae, dignissimos sint quo odit! Hic unde tempore veniam temporibus dolorem totam! Velit at in, distinctio accusamus quasi minima.
    Officiis fuga natus assumenda ipsa quaerat, voluptatem rerum voluptas, dicta minus odit, sit earum nobis! Recusandae labore minus rerum modi minima est totam deleniti, eligendi sint quasi adipisci at iure?
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias suscipit dignissimos porro nihil commodi et libero, mollitia ipsa. Officia quidem delectus nemo magni doloribus facilis iste rerum cum eum soluta!
    Omnis laboriosam illo nisi! Unde tempora exercitationem culpa, architecto dignissimos eum ratione amet doloremque, quam expedita laboriosam voluptas laborum ipsam aliquid sit saepe hic suscipit quidem illum molestiae nisi soluta.
    Eveniet natus autem vitae, quasi praesentium pariatur nulla dolorem repellat? Quidem eos eum consectetur eaque mollitia laboriosam vitae libero fugit perspiciatis debitis officiis beatae, commodi odio id reprehenderit tenetur tempora.
    Deserunt assumenda debitis, ullam mollitia molestias neque iste obcaecati commodi, vitae quasi laborum aperiam libero itaque eveniet eaque nihil explicabo impedit maxime, ducimus dolores. Rerum voluptate praesentium doloremque dolor autem!
    Vitae eius adipisci quisquam, aliquid nemo nostrum inventore rerum molestiae iure vel officia, delectus reiciendis autem dolore, enim earum. Doloremque autem vero amet enim, possimus animi temporibus consequatur aperiam cum.
    Fugit aperiam minus expedita voluptates dolor! Quia nihil ducimus dolores error aliquid totam eos alias non, cupiditate tenetur officia necessitatibus odio distinctio sequi quas nostrum, esse dolore vero consectetur earum.
    Sunt ratione id totam, itaque doloremque, consectetur pariatur, quisquam deleniti expedita asperiores molestias perspiciatis eius. Rem ratione sapiente rerum eum accusamus maxime quos. Corporis, autem ipsum. At velit sunt tempora!
    Animi blanditiis officia, reiciendis hic totam amet ea repellendus voluptatem quae eos! Sunt debitis pariatur perferendis harum consequatur natus cumque sapiente minus ut quae, quo reprehenderit ratione exercitationem omnis tenetur!
    Nesciunt enim mollitia non rerum similique rem nisi ab corrupti, ea commodi quas! Commodi repudiandae alias reprehenderit deleniti magni repellendus voluptatibus quod aperiam, veniam laborum distinctio molestiae consequuntur corporis soluta.
    Possimus dolore dolores neque distinctio obcaecati praesentium, perspiciatis saepe autem mollitia repellendus quos nulla aliquam alias temporibus, illum deleniti nesciunt, veritatis et odio. Tempore aspernatur odit, explicabo nulla totam cupiditate.
  </div>
  <div class="secondary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi doloremque tempore dicta nisi vel omnis, rem repudiandae explicabo provident voluptatibus ut magnam atque natus cumque necessitatibus quisquam. Nesciunt, minus maiores.</div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This does seem to solve the issue visually, however, I feel like this is kind of "hacky"? I'm not sure. Positioning the left side absolutely kind of defeats the purpose of having the grid, doesn't it?

Comment: @cwardle this is because everyone think that CSS grid or Flexbox is the magic tool for everything and when we see float or position:absolute we think it's hacky. It's not, I used a feature of CSS to achieve your requirement so this is a solution not a hack because what you described is not a CSS grid use case. As you said, it solves the issue so it's a viable solution

Comment: Don't know where that aggressive undertone comes from but if I offended you in any way, I apologize. That was not my intention. And for the record, I wasn't the one who downvoted your answer either.
I don't think that absolute positioning or floats are hacky per-se. They obviously have their use-cases. I just think that positioning an element absolutely over one half of a grid is not the best use of the grid because that way the grid is only used to stack the posts on the right side, which is the default behaviour of display: block.

Comment: I am also curious why you think this is not a use-case for a grid. I have a multi-dimensional layout with rows and columns, and I want one element to span multiple rows while other elements stay confined to their grid cells.

Comment: @cwardle where do you see aggressive undertone :) I gave you the reason why my solution is valid (I also never complained about the downvote as I don't really care about)

Comment: @cwardle *I am also curious why you think this is not a use-case for a grid.* --> simply because you cannot achieve it using CSS grid. If you want to can still wait for more answer. you will either get a complex *hacky* code that achieve this using CSS grid or another alternative (like I did)

Comment: @cwardle *because that way the grid is only used to stack the posts on the right side* --> not only this, I am using CSS grid here to have your equal-height items. If the requirement of equal height is not needed, I would have used block element without CSS grid

Comment: _where do you see aggressive undertone_ I jumped to conclusions then, my bad.
Tbh, I spent all day yesterday trying to figure it out but couldn't. So I am on the cusp of believing that it's not possible with grid, like you said, but the layout just seems so grid-ish to me :D And you are right, I overlooked the grid keeping the columns at equal height too. I will wait a while longer if anyone comes up with another idea but if not, I will accept this as my answer as it did solve the issue albeit in an (for me) unexpected way. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

This appears to work for me using your snippet if I simply remove the `grid-template-rows` and increase the height of that container:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  column-gap: 1rem;
  padding: 2rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.primary {
  grid-row: 1 / -1;
  position: relative;
  max-height: 500px;
  background: #cecece;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.primary:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(transparent 200px, #fff);
}

.secondary {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  background: #aaa;
  margin-block-end: 1rem;
}

.secondary:last-child {
  margin-block-end: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="primary">
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A illo nisi, sint odio repellat id enim totam. Aliquid nobis ducimus veniam totam eos et reiciendis porro illum sequi distinctio? Aliquam.
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus nulla amet perferendis iure veniam? Obcaecati molestiae laborum similique voluptatibus vel libero? Molestias deserunt nemo et consequuntur quam, saepe quo ratione?
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum ut aperiam molestiae cumque nam reprehenderit repellat, quas omnis, delectus possimus id. Enim delectus quasi et cumque quas, temporibus odio alias?
    Sequi ullam nostrum nesciunt. Sed distinctio illo eos odit repellendus eum incidunt ex libero mollitia rerum, veritatis cumque pariatur sapiente aliquid autem maiores quia itaque voluptates quidem dolore ratione doloremque!
    Ea, illum quibusdam dolores enim ex laborum voluptate repellendus nostrum dicta magnam est temporibus ipsa quisquam aut placeat cupiditate animi earum optio maiores. Eos voluptatibus ad, provident optio eligendi numquam.
    Aliquam, consectetur iste eveniet ipsam iusto pariatur exercitationem, incidunt perspiciatis nostrum repudiandae, dignissimos sint quo odit! Hic unde tempore veniam temporibus dolorem totam! Velit at in, distinctio accusamus quasi minima.
    Officiis fuga natus assumenda ipsa quaerat, voluptatem rerum voluptas, dicta minus odit, sit earum nobis! Recusandae labore minus rerum modi minima est totam deleniti, eligendi sint quasi adipisci at iure?
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias suscipit dignissimos porro nihil commodi et libero, mollitia ipsa. Officia quidem delectus nemo magni doloribus facilis iste rerum cum eum soluta!
    Omnis laboriosam illo nisi! Unde tempora exercitationem culpa, architecto dignissimos eum ratione amet doloremque, quam expedita laboriosam voluptas laborum ipsam aliquid sit saepe hic suscipit quidem illum molestiae nisi soluta.
    Eveniet natus autem vitae, quasi praesentium pariatur nulla dolorem repellat? Quidem eos eum consectetur eaque mollitia laboriosam vitae libero fugit perspiciatis debitis officiis beatae, commodi odio id reprehenderit tenetur tempora.
    Deserunt assumenda debitis, ullam mollitia molestias neque iste obcaecati commodi, vitae quasi laborum aperiam libero itaque eveniet eaque nihil explicabo impedit maxime, ducimus dolores. Rerum voluptate praesentium doloremque dolor autem!
    Vitae eius adipisci quisquam, aliquid nemo nostrum inventore rerum molestiae iure vel officia, delectus reiciendis autem dolore, enim earum. Doloremque autem vero amet enim, possimus animi temporibus consequatur aperiam cum.
    Fugit aperiam minus expedita voluptates dolor! Quia nihil ducimus dolores error aliquid totam eos alias non, cupiditate tenetur officia necessitatibus odio distinctio sequi quas nostrum, esse dolore vero consectetur earum.
    Sunt ratione id totam, itaque doloremque, consectetur pariatur, quisquam deleniti expedita asperiores molestias perspiciatis eius. Rem ratione sapiente rerum eum accusamus maxime quos. Corporis, autem ipsum. At velit sunt tempora!
    Animi blanditiis officia, reiciendis hic totam amet ea repellendus voluptatem quae eos! Sunt debitis pariatur perferendis harum consequatur natus cumque sapiente minus ut quae, quo reprehenderit ratione exercitationem omnis tenetur!
    Nesciunt enim mollitia non rerum similique rem nisi ab corrupti, ea commodi quas! Commodi repudiandae alias reprehenderit deleniti magni repellendus voluptatibus quod aperiam, veniam laborum distinctio molestiae consequuntur corporis soluta.
    Possimus dolore dolores neque distinctio obcaecati praesentium, perspiciatis saepe autem mollitia repellendus quos nulla aliquam alias temporibus, illum deleniti nesciunt, veritatis et odio. Tempore aspernatur odit, explicabo nulla totam cupiditate.
  </div>
  <div class="secondary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi doloremque tempore dicta nisi vel omnis, rem repudiandae explicabo provident voluptatibus ut magnam atque natus cumque necessitatibus quisquam. Nesciunt, minus maiores.</div>
  <div class="secondary">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur voluptas vel blanditiis corrupti earum, ipsa quasi corporis dignissimos doloribus sunt, laudantium exercitationem natus, sit accusamus facere quisquam suscipit reiciendis mollitia.</div>
  <div class="secondary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab porro, animi a, molestiae expedita veritatis recusandae repudiandae eligendi id deserunt tempore tenetur unde iste, earum sed nulla quis. Fuga, minus!</div>
</div>
```

Here it is full height, if you didn't want to fade out the content:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  column-gap: 1rem;
  padding: 2rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.primary {
  grid-row: 1 / -1;
  position: relative;
  background: #cecece;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.secondary {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  background: #aaa;
  margin-block-end: 1rem;
}

.secondary:last-child {
  margin-block-end: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="primary">
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A illo nisi, sint odio repellat id enim totam. Aliquid nobis ducimus veniam totam eos et reiciendis porro illum sequi distinctio? Aliquam.
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus nulla amet perferendis iure veniam? Obcaecati molestiae laborum similique voluptatibus vel libero? Molestias deserunt nemo et consequuntur quam, saepe quo ratione?
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum ut aperiam molestiae cumque nam reprehenderit repellat, quas omnis, delectus possimus id. Enim delectus quasi et cumque quas, temporibus odio alias?
    Sequi ullam nostrum nesciunt. Sed distinctio illo eos odit repellendus eum incidunt ex libero mollitia rerum, veritatis cumque pariatur sapiente aliquid autem maiores quia itaque voluptates quidem dolore ratione doloremque!
    Ea, illum quibusdam dolores enim ex laborum voluptate repellendus nostrum dicta magnam est temporibus ipsa quisquam aut placeat cupiditate animi earum optio maiores. Eos voluptatibus ad, provident optio eligendi numquam.
    Aliquam, consectetur iste eveniet ipsam iusto pariatur exercitationem, incidunt perspiciatis nostrum repudiandae, dignissimos sint quo odit! Hic unde tempore veniam temporibus dolorem totam! Velit at in, distinctio accusamus quasi minima.
    Officiis fuga natus assumenda ipsa quaerat, voluptatem rerum voluptas, dicta minus odit, sit earum nobis! Recusandae labore minus rerum modi minima est totam deleniti, eligendi sint quasi adipisci at iure?
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias suscipit dignissimos porro nihil commodi et libero, mollitia ipsa. Officia quidem delectus nemo magni doloribus facilis iste rerum cum eum soluta!
    Omnis laboriosam illo nisi! Unde tempora exercitationem culpa, architecto dignissimos eum ratione amet doloremque, quam expedita laboriosam voluptas laborum ipsam aliquid sit saepe hic suscipit quidem illum molestiae nisi soluta.
    Eveniet natus autem vitae, quasi praesentium pariatur nulla dolorem repellat? Quidem eos eum consectetur eaque mollitia laboriosam vitae libero fugit perspiciatis debitis officiis beatae, commodi odio id reprehenderit tenetur tempora.
    Deserunt assumenda debitis, ullam mollitia molestias neque iste obcaecati commodi, vitae quasi laborum aperiam libero itaque eveniet eaque nihil explicabo impedit maxime, ducimus dolores. Rerum voluptate praesentium doloremque dolor autem!
    Vitae eius adipisci quisquam, aliquid nemo nostrum inventore rerum molestiae iure vel officia, delectus reiciendis autem dolore, enim earum. Doloremque autem vero amet enim, possimus animi temporibus consequatur aperiam cum.
    Fugit aperiam minus expedita voluptates dolor! Quia nihil ducimus dolores error aliquid totam eos alias non, cupiditate tenetur officia necessitatibus odio distinctio sequi quas nostrum, esse dolore vero consectetur earum.
    Sunt ratione id totam, itaque doloremque, consectetur pariatur, quisquam deleniti expedita asperiores molestias perspiciatis eius. Rem ratione sapiente rerum eum accusamus maxime quos. Corporis, autem ipsum. At velit sunt tempora!
    Animi blanditiis officia, reiciendis hic totam amet ea repellendus voluptatem quae eos! Sunt debitis pariatur perferendis harum consequatur natus cumque sapiente minus ut quae, quo reprehenderit ratione exercitationem omnis tenetur!
    Nesciunt enim mollitia non rerum similique rem nisi ab corrupti, ea commodi quas! Commodi repudiandae alias reprehenderit deleniti magni repellendus voluptatibus quod aperiam, veniam laborum distinctio molestiae consequuntur corporis soluta.
    Possimus dolore dolores neque distinctio obcaecati praesentium, perspiciatis saepe autem mollitia repellendus quos nulla aliquam alias temporibus, illum deleniti nesciunt, veritatis et odio. Tempore aspernatur odit, explicabo nulla totam cupiditate.
  </div>
  <div class="secondary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi doloremque tempore dicta nisi vel omnis, rem repudiandae explicabo provident voluptatibus ut magnam atque natus cumque necessitatibus quisquam. Nesciunt, minus maiores.</div>
  <div class="secondary">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur voluptas vel blanditiis corrupti earum, ipsa quasi corporis dignissimos doloribus sunt, laudantium exercitationem natus, sit accusamus facere quisquam suscipit reiciendis mollitia.</div>
  <div class="secondary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab porro, animi a, molestiae expedita veritatis recusandae repudiandae eligendi id deserunt tempore tenetur unde iste, earum sed nulla quis. Fuga, minus!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. I'm not sure if I'm missing something, but if I do that, the left column is only one grid row "tall" and the first post on the right is just stretched to fill that same role. 
The end result I am seeking would be that the left column spans the entire height of the right column though.

Comment: Strange. When I preview the snippet even here on StackOverflow, it fills the full height of all rows until the content ends. What browser are you working in?

Comment: Interesting indeed. I tested it in Firefox and Chromium (on Linux) and this is what I saw in either of them: https://imgur.com/a/2uknmDW
Screenshots show FF but it looks the same in Chromium. Did you use a different browser or OS? Might be a OS-specific difference in browser implementation.